# Substring in Java - how to break sentence and save as different strings

Tags: java, substring

I want to save part of sentence (which is a String) into another string.

For example :

String s = " **By 1889, central telephone exchange operators were known as 'hello-girls' due to the association between the greeting and the telephone** "

I want to save "By 1889, central telephone exchange operators were known as" into one string

and

**"hello-girls' due to the association between the greeting and the telephone" into another.**

How to do so?

Comment: what is the criteria to split a given string ? and what happens to the space between **known as[SPACE]"hello-girls** ?

Comment: Do you want to split it by characters? a certain amount of characters? Do you want to do this more than once? Do you want to split it when it gets to a certain character? You should look into delimiters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
int index = s.indexOf("'hello-girls'");
System.out.println(s.substring(0, index ));
System.out.println(s.substring(index));
```

Output:

```
 By 1889, central telephone exchange operators were known as 
'hello-girls' due to the association between the greeting and the telephone
```

Doc:

- [String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))
- [int indexOf(int ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

```
    String s = " By 1889, central telephone exchange operators were known as 'hello-girls' due to the association between the greeting and the telephone ";
    int index=s.indexOf("'");
    String s1=s.substring(0,index);
    String s2=s.substring(index,s.length()-1);
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);
```

See this ideone https://ideone.com/iB5quw

Comment: See the link of ideone https://ideone.com/iB5quw

Answer (score 2):

If this is because of the word 'hello-girls' you could do :

```
int index = s.indexOf("'hello-girls'"));

String firstPart = s.substring(0, index);
String secondPart = s.substring(index);
```

Note that the firstPart string would end with an empty space. You could easily remove it by changing the above code with :

```
String firstPart = s.substring(0, index - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = " By 1889, central telephone exchange operators " +
            "were known as 'hello-girls' due to the association " +
            "between the greeting and the telephone ";
```

First way:

```
String[] strings = s.split("as ");

String first = strings[0] + "as";
// "By 1889, central telephone exchange operators were known as"

String second = strings[1];
// "'hello-girls' due to the association between the greeting and the telephone"
```

Second way:

```
String separator = " as ";
int firstLength = s.indexOf(separator) + separator.length();

String first = s.substring(0, firstLength);
// "By 1889, central telephone exchange operators were known as"

String second = s.substring(firstLength);
// "'hello-girls' due to the association between the greeting and the telephone"
```